# How do I embed TFS charts in my page?

Tags: tfs

I need to embed charts from TFS (Microsoft Team Foundation Server) in a simple HTML page. The chart editor allows me to copy the query URL, but i don't see any elegant way to embed the chart itself. Any advise on how to get individual charts from a TFS instance on my own web page?

Answer (score 0):

At present, you don't. There's no supported way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Allow you to copy the query URL cause it's **Query-based** charts which generate data from the work item tracking data store and therefore displays the most recent data. You could add it to dashboard, but it's not able to embed  them in a normal HTML page outside of TFS.

There has been a related uservoice, which you could use the Chart for work items widget:

> **Embed Dashboard Widgets outside of VSTS / TFS**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13784832-embed-dashboard-widgets-outside-of-vsts-tfs

You could vote up for it and TFS admin/PM will kindly review your suggestion.